# Strange behaviour: apache redirects string to string.js

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

Can someone explain me, why does apache rewrite 'string' to 'string.js'? I didn't find anything on google and I wonder, how to turn it off…

Comment: we're going to need a little more information than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are providing very little information. That said, the cause of your problem is *probably* the `MultiViews` feature that can under certain circumstances [automagically add extensions](http://wiki.kartbuilding.net/index.php/Apache#Multiviews_-_Automatically_append_file_extension).

Try adding this to a `.htaccess` file or to your central server config:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't know how to describe it more detailed, but you understood the issue perfectly though! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The feature seems to be useful, but exactly on my current project, I don't want to have it =D Thx again